# Can I lock down the user information lists globally?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, permissions

I want to restrict users from having read access to user information lists within my entire farm. Is this even possible? If so, how can I achieve this with powershell?

Comment: Wouldn't this negatively affect people picker fields? Why do you want to lock down the user information list?

Comment: @wjervis there are plenty of solutions where security over functionality is desired

Comment: I understand that, I just don't understand what security you're gaining by locking this list down.

Comment: @wjervis the list exposes names and structures of an organization - that's closely guarded information in a lot of applications.

Comment: Information that's gathered from user profile services.  Why not simply mark those properties that are confidential as not replicable?

Comment: I believe that the user information list on each site is writeable by everyone because they are not added to the list until they visit the site (for the most part). You might be able to get away with ghosting and hosing the view pages. Is security by obscurity sufficient?

Comment: @ghangas It's the best option posted so far - happy to accept as an answer/bounty if you can outline the approach in more detail if something more complete doesn't get posted in the next couple of days.

Comment: Thank you for the offer, as I researched the option my proposal offered no additional real or perceived security. Please forgive the misstep and late response

Answer (score -1):

If your User Information List (single Site Collection) contains information about organizations that you don't want everyone to see, then move that information somewhere else. For example, you could built a Personnel roster that contains everyone in your organization, and limit access to that roster. Then, remove the private information columns from the User Information List.

If this information is in Active Directory, then everyone on your network can see this information anyway, if they know where to look.

If you are using User Profile Service and updating all your site collections from Central Admin, then you can control which fields are shared with the site collections.